# Easiest way to attach this HDX inline filter to replace my American Plumber WICA inline filter

Tags: plumbing

I threw out this American Plimber inline filter:

[[image: WICA Inline filter]]
[[image: WICA Inline filter]]

It was over a decade old, and yes I can replace it, but I'd rather use this HDX one:

[[image: HDX Filter]]
[[image: HDX Filter Side view]]

I have a torch and a hacksaw. I have plenty of slack in my copper line. I have the following collars and fittings:

[[image: Collars]]
[[image: Fittings]]
[[image: Tourch]]

Is the best thing to do just to saw off the plastic couplings and then soldier on the metal ones?

Comment: Doesn't that HDX filter have push on connectors on both sides?  So can't you just use a tubing cutter (not a saw) to cleanly cut the copper and push it into the filter?

Comment: @JPhi1618 yes once I realized that the plastic conectors were push to connect, I came to the conclusion that push to connect works for copper as well as flex line.

Comment: Yea, the pipes are clever because the _outside_ diameter is the same for all materials so the connectors work for various pipe types.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to take off the plastic connectors on each end of copper. After that I realized since ther were push to connect then I could use push to connect on copper as well as flex line. At that point I cleaned the copper ends with a green 3m scouring pad, and installed the filter with no soldering and none of the brass parts.

Comment: Don't forget to secure it to something with strapping.

Comment: @ojait the old filter had none and it lasted a decade.  I will put that on my todo though.

Comment: It might protect the 1/4 inch lines from pulling free.

Comment: Wait. What? A decade? I believe water filters should be replaced every 3-6 months. Or it should be printed on the filter label.

Comment: @ojait yes the filter was installed longer than I owned the house. I got a new fridge so I decided it was time to deal with the matter. I bought the house from the estate of a widow. I assume when the husband died, the widow didn't know to have the filter in the ceiling of the basement changed.